# Azure Node.JS Tutorial Default Template Engine

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Im following the tutorial [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-nodejs-application/#_Toc395783180). I when trying to run the project at this point. I get an error saying that there is no defined templating engine. The tutorial has us remove the app.use

Below is my console error when trying to go through the tutorial. Just to be sure I went back through it three times. I get the same error. I notice in the History.md that this was addressed but I cant figure out what if anything i am supposed to do with that info. Can you advise?

This is the tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-nodejs-application/

I get the error on trying to run npm start to see the todo UI. When I run start at the beginning of the tutorial, it works.

Thank you.

---

```
Kaona (master *) todo $ npm start
> todo@0.0.0 start /Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo

> node ./bin/www



/Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62

    throw new Error('No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.');

    ^



Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

    at new View (/Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)

    at EventEmitter.render (/Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)

    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)

    at /Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/routes/tasklist.js:27:17

    at /Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/models/taskDao.js:43:17

    at Base.defineClass._toArrayImplementation (/Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/documentdb/lib/queryIterator.js:187:17)

    at /Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/documentdb/lib/queryIterator.js:183:26

    at /Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/documentdb/lib/queryIterator.js:234:17

    at successCallback (/Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/documentdb/lib/documentclient.js:2069:17)

    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/Kaona/GitHub/todo/node_modules/documentdb/lib/request.js:84:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per @ryancrawcour @larrymaccherone's direction. The solution is to add app.set('view engine', 'jade'); to the app.js file in the tutorial. See [Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595282/error-no-default-engine-was-specified-and-no-extension-was-provided)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, I guess your machine is a Mac, but I think my steps below on linux that's similar with yours on MacOS.

The tutorial sample shows a local node app created by express generator for using Azure DocumentDB.

So the first step is creating an Azure DocumentDB instance on Azure new portal. I think it's simple, and copy the connection information of the DocumentDB created for the express app.

To create a express app like the tutorial doing, I did the steps below.

1. Command `npm install express-generator -g`

   > On MacOS, may need to add the prefix cmd `sudo` because it's for global env, see http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).
2. Command `express todo`

   > Generate a empty express app via express generator
3. Command `cd todo && npm install`

   > installation for dependent libraries registed in the `package.json`
4. Now, you can command `npm start` in the dir `todo` and browse the url `http://localhost:3000`
5. Command `git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/documentdb-node-todo-app.git` from Github project https://github.com/Azure-Samples/documentdb-node-todo-app and copy the files of the path `src` of git repo to the dir `todo`.
6. Edit & configure the `config.js` with the connection information of your DocumentDB.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.