# Nodejs Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this error when i load my nodejs on my browser
[image]

what is the possible problem?

this is the code : on `/var/nodejs_conference/node_modules/express/lib/view.js`

```
function View(name, options) {
  var opts = options || {};

  this.defaultEngine = opts.defaultEngine;
  this.ext = extname(name);
  this.name = name;
  this.root = opts.root;

  if (!this.ext && !this.defaultEngine) {
    throw new Error('No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.');
  }

}
```

this is my app.js code

[image]
thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595282/error-no-default-engine-was-specified-and-no-extension-was-provided)

Comment: You need to show the code in `/var/nodejs_conference/app.js`, around line 58... (this is the code that's most likely causing your error)