# get error while console.log my form data to my server

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, body-parser

I am trying to `console.log` my data get post from form to /persons endpoint.But getting error undefined or Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

ERROR

```
listening
undefined
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
 at new View (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
at EventEmitter.render (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
at ServerResponse.render (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
at /home/mohit/edx-proj/server.js:42:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/home/mohit/edx-
proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var app=express();
app.get(`/`,function(request,response){
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      response.write("sfewqcfnvsjv")
      response.write('<form action="/persons" method="post" >');
      response.write('<input type="number" name="filetoupload"><br>');
      response.write('<input type="text" name="filetoupload"><br>');
      response.write('<input type="text" name="filetoupload"><br>');
      response.write('<input type="submit">');
      response.write('</form>');
      response.end()
 });

app.post('/persons',urlencodedParser,function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render('persons',{qs:req.query});
});

app.listen(8000,function(){
    console.log("listen:8000")
})
```

Please let me know what I am missing and thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595282/error-no-default-engine-was-specified-and-no-extension-was-provided

Comment: i added       app.set('view engine', 'html');
 but error   Cannot find module 'html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified which of the view engine,

that is either:

To render in HTML

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

or even in json format

```
res.json({ error: err })
```

or to render in ejs

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

or to render in jade/pug

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

**Note:** you're to use either *jade* or *pug* depending on what format your files are, and not to use `app.set('view engine', 'jade');` `app.set('view engine', 'pug');` together, you can read more about [jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade) and [pug](https://pugjs.org)

You need to specify that.

Comment: And the `undefined` right before the error is because `req.body` doesn't exist on the `req` object. You may be `POST`'ing with invalid content type.

Comment: just a note: Jade = pug