# Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters, Mongoose ObjectId err

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I actually searched a ton and I saw a ton of mentions of my problem here but none of the things I tried helped me fix the issue i'm having.

I have a Room Scheme that looks like this:

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;
const roomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
users: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}],
messages: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Message',
}],
post: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }
});
```

As you can see I have an array of users with ref to another schema Users

I'm trying to query all the Rooms that has a User ObjectId in it (search ObjectId in an array).

while I can easily get this with querying mongo from cmd using this:

```
db.users.find({users:ObjectId('THE_OBJECT_ID')});
```

when I try to get the same while using mongoose it fails with:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

Here is how my route and find looks like:

```
  app.route('/rooms/list/:user_id')
    .get((req, res) => {
        var query = { users: "USER_ID" };
        Room.find(query ).populate('messages').then((data) => {
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
     })
```

I tried to create type of object ID and use it but it still doesn't work.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
userId = 'THE_USER_ID';
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId);
```

and than

```
Rooms.find({'users': id });
```

but it still doesn't work.

I also tried altering my query search using $in, $elemmatch it worked on cmd but failed when querying using mongoose.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input should be `user_id`, convert it to `ObjectId()` and then query. So value of `user_id` should be a string that obeys `ObjectId()`'s restrictions, You can take string from existing doc's `ObjectId()` & test your `get` api..

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :**

If you check this :

```
var query = { users: "USER_ID" };

(Or)

userId = 'THE_USER_ID';
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId);
```

What are you trying to do here ?  You are passing in string `USER_ID` or `THE_USER_ID` as input and trying to convert it to type of `ObjectId()`. But string inside [ObjectId()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) has certain restrictions which is why mongoose is failing to convert passed in string value to `ObjectId()` and getting error'd out.

Try this code :

**Code :**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


app.route('/rooms/list/:user_id')
    .get((req, res) => {
        var query = { users: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.user_id) };
        Room.find(query).populate('messages').then((data) => {
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
```

Your input should be value of `user_id` (Which will be string) - Convert it to `ObjectId()` and then query DB. So value of **user_id** should be a string that obeys **ObjectId()**'s restrictions, You can take string from one of existing doc's `ObjectId()` & test your get api.

Comment: Server fails on:
    var query = { users: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.user_id) };
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Comment: @Yonihodeffi : try to debug with logs, this error shouldn’t be from that part of code..Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595282/error-no-default-engine-was-specified-and-no-extension-was-provided

Comment: I was able to fix the err, though query still returns empty result which is weird since querying directly to mongo yields stuff

Comment: @Yonihodeffi : Since you're able to fix this error this question is resolved, You can close this. To test why you're getting this error - print `req.params.user_id` and check if you'r getting a value that exists in atleast one docs `_id` field, Also check if conversion of string to `ObjectId()` is properly working..