# Firebase hosting dynamic index.html based on domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Our application supports multiple domains. Is there a way to serve a different index.html file based on a domain in the request?

It doesn't look like firebase rewrites support that https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

Business requirement: is to be able to serve different meta tags based on the domain

Current approach: have a separate hosting bucket for each domain that requires custom meta tags. This generally works but it has a problem of scale and we are simply duplicating resources as we need to upload the same files to every bucket.

Reviewed solution: to have 1 bucket and serve entry point (index.html) dynamically via firebase functions.
Cons:

- Function needs to be redeployed every time we deploy new version
- Creates dependency between hosting and functions
  We need to make sure that new index.html is served only after files are deployed. When you do `firebase deploy` it actually takes care of the order but wouldn’t be surprised if there are some edge cases
- Makes it harder to do rollbacks as we would need to rollback file that function serves

Reviewed solution 2: Similar to reviewed solution above but instead of storing a file in functions folder we could download it via network request from the latest version of hosting folder

Answer (score 0):

Firebase supports dynamic rendering by rewriting paths to Cloud Functions. You could simply rewrite every path to a Cloud Function which generates a dynamic index.html file based on the domain the request comes from.

Here is the Firebase documentation for rewrites to Cloud Functions:

```json
    "hosting": {
      "rewrites": [ {
        "source": "/bigben",
        "function": "bigben",
        "region": "us-central1"
      } ]
    }
```

[Configuring Firebase Hosting behaviour](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config)

Here is another question which has a similar problem:
[Dynamic rendering with Firebase Functions and Firebase Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935091/dynamic-rendering-with-firebase-functions-and-firebase-hosting)

You could use a template engine like EJS for generating dynamic HTML files. Your Cloud Function would prepare the HTML file and serve it when it's done.
[EJS - Embedded JavaScript](https://ejs.co/)